# What is wrong with my CS I class program?

Tags: java

I keep getting an error " ')' expected " in my intro to java class's program.

What are the problems with this code designed to represent a user of a bank account? Why am I getting these errors? How can I fix these problems?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code Below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Customer
{
  private long acctNum;
  private String name;
  private double balance = 0;

  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$0.00"); 

  public Customer(long acctNum, String name)
  {
    this.acctNum = acctNum;
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = 0.00;
  }

  public void deposit(double in)
  {
    this.balance = this.balance + in;
  }

  public void withdraw(double out)
  {
    *if((this.balance - out) !>= 0.0)*
    {
      System.out.println("Invalid amount to withdraw.");
    }
    *else*
    {
      this.balance = this.balance - out;
    }
  }

  public void calcInterest()
  {
    *if(this.balance !> 0.0)*
    {
      System.out.println("No interest added to an empty account.");
    }
    *else*
    {
      this.balance = (this.balance)*1.03;
    }
  }

  public double getBalance()
  {
    return df.format(this.balance);
  }

}
```

Comment: When asking questions like this please add a line number or highlight the code as described in the error message.

Comment: at several lines in your code you've written !> what is that? There is no such operation in java. What is it that is required for you to do in those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one thing I noticed is that you are using operators such as !>= and !> when they don't exist. If you want to say something is NOT greater than or equal to, or NOT greater than, then put a NOT operator (!) before the condition. For example, have

```
if(!(this.balance - out >= 0.0))
```

and

```
if(!(this.balance > 0.0))
```

instead of what you had before.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
*if((this.balance - out) !>= 0.0)*
```

should change to

```
if((this.balance - out) < 0.0)
```

Second

```
*if(this.balance !> 0.0)*
```

should change to

```
if(this.balance <= 0.0)
```

and

```
return df.format(this.balance);
```

should change to

```
return Double.valueOf(this.balance);
```

and then your program will start working

Hope it helps